# Nginx randomly returning 500 error on static files

Tags: javascript, nginx, static

I'm running a React.js application on my server. It works most of the time, but sometime I randomly receive a 500 error and I get a white screen (of death). After debugging it seems like it's a nginx issue. My `nginx.conf` is shown below, is there anything configured incorrectly?

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites/*;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$query_string;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
    }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /500.html;
        location = /500.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you say whether there is a pattern to the requests that trigger 500 errors? Do you have an 'error_log' directive, if not could you add one and see what nginx says when the error occurs.